# Nodejs MQTT: unsubscribe is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, node-modules

I have inplemented MQTT well but I am experiencing an issue with `unsubscribe` method. All other functions (`mqttCon.publish() , mqttCon.subscribe(), mqttCon.on()...`) are working well except this. I have checked the spelling and even done `ctrl +click` and it takes me to the library implementation meaning it is the right method and referenced well yet I keep getting the error below. How can I solve it?

This is the line:  **`mqttCon.unsubscribe(topic)`**

```
TypeError: mqttCon.unsubscribe is not a function

    at noopHandler (/home/dev/project-dir/src/mqtt/processMessage.js:5:13)
    at module.exports (/home/dev/project-dir/src/mqtt/processMessage.js:10:20)
    at MqttClient.client.on (/home/dev/project-dir/src/mqtt/mqttCon.js:16:13)
    at MqttClient.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at MqttClient._handlePublish (/home/dev/project-dir/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:1271:12)
    at MqttClient._handlePacket (/home/dev/project-dir/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:410:12)
    at work (/home/dev/project-dir/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:321:12)
    at Writable.writable._write (/home/dev/project-dir/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:335:5)
    at doWrite (/home/dev/project-dir/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:428:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/dev/project-dir/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:417:5)
```

**NOTE**: I am using ES6(Emacscript 6+) javascript and **not** Typescript.
Nodejs `12.18.1` and npm `6.14.6`

Here is my connection code `mqttCon.js`:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
const processMessage = require('./processMessage')
const logger = require('../logConf')
const options = {
    host: '',
    port: '',
    username:'',
    password: '',
    protocol: ''
};
const client = mqtt.connect(options)
client.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("MQTT connected  with status: " + client.connected);
    if (client.connected) {
        client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
            processMessage(topic, String(message))
        })
    }
})
client.on('error', error => {
    console.log(error,'ERROR')
    logger.errorLogger.error(error)
})
client.on('reconnect', error => {
    console.log(error,'RECONNECT')
    logger.errorLogger.error(error)
})
client.on('close', error => {
    console.log(error,'CLOSE')
    logger.errorLogger.error(error)
})
client.on('disconnect', error => {
    console.log(error,'DISCONNECT')
    logger.errorLogger.error(error)
})
client.on('offline', error => {
    console.log(error,'OFFLINE')
    logger.errorLogger.error(error)
})
module.exports = client
```

This is the `processMessage.js` :

```
const mqttCon = require('./mqttCon')
const logger = require('../logConf')
let noopHandler = (topic, message) => {
    console.log(String(message))
    mqttCon.unsubscribe(topic)    //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS OCCURRING *******************
}
module.exports = (topic, message) => {
    switch (topic) {
        case 'NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOP':
            return noopHandler(topic, message)
        case 'anotherTopic':
            // return handleAnotherTopic(String(message))
            return
        default:
            logger.errorLogger.error(new Error(`No handler for topic ${topic}`))

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mqttCon.js file has no `client.prototype.unsubscribe = function() {}`, so the error is correct. You are defining `client` as a module, but you are really needing to call `mqtt.unsubscribe()` somewhere.  So you need to either add an `unsubscribe()` function to the `client` constant (which really should be a `var` in this case), or call the `mqtt.unsubscribe()` function after requiring the mqtt module in your processMessage.js file....which I think goes against what you are trying to do anyway.  You might want to read up a bit more about how module.exports actually works: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

UPDATE:
The above influenced my thoughts and the issue was that I was importing `processMessage.js` which inturn imports `mqttCon.js` which imported it. Circular import, meaning `mqttCon`(mqttClient) was always not yet initialized inside `processMessage.js`. The solution was that I imported `processMessage.js` inside `client.on('connect'....)...` block when client is already initialized and exported well as a module like below:

```js
client.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("MQTT connected  with status: " + client.connected);
    if (client.connected) {
        client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
            require('./processMessage')(topic, String(message))
        })
    }
})
```